# php mysql syntax error but i don't see it?

Tags: php, mysql

can someone please tell me what is wrong with this query?

```
     $sql = "INSERT INTO vendors (business_name, address, description, contact_name,
     contact_phone, alt_phone, url, level, use_me) 
     VALUES($_POST['business_name'],
       $_POST['address'],
       $_POST['description'],
       $_POST['contact_name'],
       $_POST['contact_phone'],
       $_POST['alt_phone'],
       $_POST['url'],
       $_POST['level'],
       $_POST['use_me'])";
```

and when try to execute, i get the error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING @ the line number where starts "VALUES"

Comment: make sure u do a `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent injection attacks on `$_POST`.

Comment: ... or another method of escaping or abstracting the values.  The preferred method is to use PDO parameterised queries these days unless you need the specialised features of mysqli.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One thing noticeable is, in your query you don't wrap the $_POST['variable'] withing single quotes. Those are most likely strings. So in your insert query, you should wrap strings within  single quotes. For example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (name,email) values('your_name','your_email');
```

But what you have in your query will read like the below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (name,email) values(your_name,your_email);
```

Without the quotes, it will produce error when executed. You should try wrapping as below :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vendors (business_name, address, description, contact_name,
 contact_phone, alt_phone, url, level, use_me) 
 VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['business_name'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact_name'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact_phone'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alt_phone'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['level'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['use_me'])."')";
```

Comment: Will break the second someone wants to enter info about Joe's Diner (due to the `'`).  No responsible answer should be injecting values directly from $_POST into an SQL string.

Comment: @cHao Yes you are absolutely right. Using the $_POST values directly  without escaping and some validations is not good programming practice and error prone also. I just tried to point out the exact problem why the code was not working in this case leaving the good practices. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

First, never inject raw data into your database.

```
$cleanData = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $post) {
    $cleanData[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $post);
}
```

Now that we're clean, the syntax error was caused by improper string syntax, but once that's solved you'll also have a problem with missing quotation marks in the query.  The following solves both problems:

```
// note the trailing quotation mark
$sql = 'INSERT INTO vendors (business_name, address, description, contact_name,
 contact_phone, alt_phone, url, level, use_me) VALUES ("';

// now let's simplify the meat of the query with an implode.
$sql .= implode('", "', array(
    $cleanData['business_name'],
    $cleanData['address'],
    $cleanData['description'],
    $cleanData['contact_name'],
    $cleanData['contact_phone'],
    $cleanData['alt_phone'],
    $cleanData['url'],
    $cleanData['level'],
    $cleanData['use_me']
));

$sql .= '")'; // and one final quotation mark, along with a closing parenthesis
```

Comment: this code will produce an error. there is a point in using mysqli, but one have to post a code only if they used it actually, despite of some noizy demands :)

Answer (score -1):

you would have to quote all the strings:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO vendors (business_name, address, description, contact_name,
 contact_phone, alt_phone, url, level, use_me) 
 VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['business_name'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact_name'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact_phone'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alt_phone'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['level']."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['use_me'])."')";
```

Also, you must either escape your strings or use prepared statements. You should really read about SQL injections, because this is very bad practice here...

Comment: Will break the second someone wants to enter info about Joe's Diner (due to the `'`). No responsible answer should be injecting values directly from $_POST into an SQL string.

Answer (score -2):

> what is wrong with this query?

EVERYTHING.

- First of all, it is not an "SQL query". From PHP's point of view it's just an ordinary *string* with no special meaning. It can be part of XML with the same problem.
- the main problem is your lack of PHP strings syntax knowledge. http://php.net/types.string for your reference. You can't write any single PHP code without studiying this page **diligently.** You can learn at least 2 ways for referencing an array member inside of a string.
- at last we come to SQL syntax with which you have problems too. You **ought** to escape every string before adding it to a query as well as enclose it in quotes.
- a bit more complicated, but no less important thing, **always forgotten** by local folks: a programming. Every time you see repetitions, it's time to start using your *programming* skills. To  reduce repetitions in your case, as every code presented here looks ugly and grows with number of fields and queries.

So, here is a sensible code to use

```
$fields = explode(",","business_name,address,description,contact_name,contact_phone,alt_phone,url,level,use_me");

$sql = "INSERT INTO vendors SET ".dbSet($fields);

function dbSet($fields) {
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $key) {
    $set .= "`$key`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$key])."', ";
  }
  return rtrim($q,", ");
}
```

note that the only variable part of this code is a list of fields. you can store a *function* in some config file and then your code become dramarically smaller and less repetitive every time you are going to INSERT or UPDATE.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is from the old mysql extension which is outrageously outdated.  mysqli arrived in 2004 and PDO in 2005.

Comment: well, mysqli require link paremerer in the procedural style and it will cost me another line in the code. I don't think mysql is THAT bad beside the fact it is no longer supported. Let me assume that I know much more on the matter and have no injection with old mysql but you fail with brand new PDO.

Comment: The fact that it's no longer supported should be enough.  But either way, `mysql_real_escape_string` still uses a link; your function just can't say which one.  If you haven't opened a connection yet, then *it will try to* -- probably using nonsensical credentials from php.ini.  (See, much like mysqli's version, `mysql_real_escape_string` uses the link to determine the charset in order to escape stuff correctly -- and it'll use the most recent open connection if you don't specify $link, trying to connect on its own if there aren't any connections yet.)

Comment: @cHao 99% of php scripts working without using a link. I think you have a bit exagerrated  the problem.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: `addslashes` works 99% of the time as well, when you're escaping for mysql.  If you're content with half-assedness, that's way fewer chars to type with about the same failure rate.  But we don't use it, because 1% failure rate is too high.

Comment: @cHao 99% of sites using mysql_real_escape_string do not use mysql_set_charset, thus, their  mysql_real_escape_string works EXACTLY THE SAME WAY as addslashes.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: The site doesn't need to use `mysql_set_charset` to see wacky results -- mysqld has its own default, which will be used if the client doesn't request a charset on connection.  (Which the mysql extension doesn't, last i checked.)  Each server can have a different default, so you kinda have to know which server you're talking to in order to guarantee you're escaping stuff correctly.

Comment: @cHao I doubt there are any mysql server in the world which has `init-connect='SET NAMES GBK'` in it's configuration. you can be sure that 99% uses latin1 as their default.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I don't care whether it's 99%, 99.9%, 50%, or any other number -- statistics don't matter.  99% is not 100%.  "You can be sure that 99% do X" means, among other things, "You can not be sure that 100% do X" and even "You can be sure that 1% *do not* do X".  I'd rather avoid having to special-case that 1%, particularly since the brokenness is as subtle as it is.

Comment: @cHao not a big deal. whoever will need that link - thay'l add it.

Answer (score -3):

Joe, the best way to troubleshoot queries when you're writing them in PHP is to print them out to your screen, and then paste that into a query field in whatever db interface program your using--phpmyadmin or navicat for example.

So:

```
 <?php

 echo $query; die();

 ?>
```

That will spit out your query and nothing else after it to the screen.

I tend to assign $_POST's to variables as I find it easier to use them in the query that way, and I am less prone to getting multiple layers of quoting confused. I've never used a $_POST directly in a query actually. Haven't tested it, but probably not the best way to code.

I don't see an error in your query jumping out at me, but from the error message you're getting, something is messed up with the quotes. printing it to the screen, you should be able to spot a missing quote, or see where you're getting the actual name of the variable rather than the stored value for it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Although the OP does have errors in the query syntax, the error that was reported was a PHP Parse error.

Comment: I am interesting where did all the comments go

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vendors (business_name, address, description, contact_name,
 contact_phone, alt_phone, url, level, use_me) 
 VALUES($_POST['business_name],
   $_POST[address],
   $_POST[description],
   $_POST[contact_name],
   $_POST[contact_phone],
   $_POST[alt_phone],
   $_POST[url],
   $_POST[level],
   $_POST[use_me])";
```

Not sure if I missed any single quotes there.

More importantly, you should be using a prepared statement or at least calling mysql_real_escape_string instead of putting those strings directly into the query.

Comment: It would be nice if the example showed how to escape or use prepared statements too.